# discord bot js, not working "rep", send random gif

Tags: javascript, discord

Trying to make an action "rep", but does not work. What is the reason?

```
message.channel.send({ embed });
    } else if (command === "rep") {
        number = 4;
        imageNumber = Math.floor (math.random()* (number - 1 + 1)) + 1;
        message.channel.send ( {files:["./rep/" + imageNumber + ".gif"]} )
```

After entering the command 'rep' I get this — [img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jokgg.png), [img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcmvu.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix this line:

```
imageNumber = Math.floor (math.random()* (number - 1 + 1)) + 1;
```

It's Math.random() not math.random();

```
imageNumber = Math.floor (Math.random()* (number - 1 + 1)) + 1;
```